# include $config->get in a external PHP function

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

Im building a script for opencart where it will send emails. Its not an extension, its a separate panel.

I have added an option in opencart where they can enable or disable this feature. The problem is that im unable to get the setting from the opencart into my script.

for an example i have the below code in my php script

```
if ($config->get('sendemails_status')) {

   $store_id = $config->get('config_store_id');

}
```

When i run that code i get this error

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Can someone let me know how can i get the above code working in my PHP script?

Comment: where $config variable has came from? can you share some more code snippet?

Comment: Is your script running within opencart or outside of it as a cron job, command line, or browser?

Comment: @billynoah Its running outside Opencart. Actaully i have built and extension that has some functions outside of Opencart.. So there will be a separate link to access that. So i want to get the language, store id and check if the extension is enabled on my external files.

Comment: just query the database

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to permissions set on the cache folder. Setting that to `755` and the files to `555` with set you home and dry.

**OR**

in `system/library/session.php` replace start session with:

```
session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/../tmp'));
```

**OR**

You did not set that variables , please check in yo database for the settings.

Comment: thank you.. I did try those but it didnt work.. Is there any specific file that i need to include to get the $config working?